# twitter-bootstrap-rails undefined local variable or method `html'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I am using `devise` with `twitter-bootstrap-rails`, but i got the error on `form_for`, any file i didn't include?

```
undefined local variable or method `html' for #<#<Class:0x007fc07b544410>:0x007fc0810b8b70>
```

Here is the code:

```
 <%= menu_group pull: :right do %>
                <% if current_user %>
                    <%= menu_item "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete%>
                <% else %>
                    <!-- error here-->
                    <%= form_for @user, url: user_session_path(:user), html => {class: "navbar-form pull-right"} do |f| -%>
                      <p><%= f.text_field :email %></p>
                      <p><%= f.password_field :password %></p>
                      <p><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></p>
                    <% end -%>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
```

`EDIT`: synax error, just copied from https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a syntax error. Do Ctrl+F to find the only occurrence of "html", and then consider why it may be failing.

```
:html =>
```

or

```
html:
```

will be your fix.

Comment: I just copied from github page: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails, a typos.

Comment: Still, this really isn't a great question for Stack Overflow. I've been there, missing syntax errors and kicking myself for it later, but definitely use Ctrl+F next time

Comment: I just mean when you see that error message, search your code for the string "html". I use grep on the command line, but Textmate's Ctrl+F is fine too. There's always a stack trace in your rails server log that will have helpful line numbers too (buried in a lot of unhelpful line numbers...) Not on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a ***colon(:)***. It should be `:html =>` or `html:`

```
<%= form_for @user, url: user_session_path(:user), :html => {class: "navbar-form pull-right"} do |f| -%>
```